# RegEx: All rows with trailing and leading space

Tags: regex, oracle

To be sorry, but this is most probably just another "where is the mistake in my regEx?"-question, during my try to determine all rows in a adress table in where the format of the "addition to the house number" is incorrect.

I would like to find all rows, in which the value violates the given requiements of:

- doesn't start or end with (white-)space
- may have any letter, including regular space, in between the first and the last character
- has a length of at least 1 and maximum 20 characters
- is not NULL

Examples: In the result there should be rows, in which the cols value

- contains a string with leading or trailing spaces, like ' auch' or 'auch '
- are more than 20 characters long

Valid results are strings like `-1`, `A`, `Haus 1`, `(Gebäude 1)`.

For this I did the fowolling query:

```
SELECT *
from table
WHERE col is not null
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (col, 'my_reg_ex_see_below');
```

I tried the following regex `^([\S])([.]{0,18}[\S]{1}})+$` which should ensure, that:

- the first character must be presend and must not be a whitespace
- the 2nd to 19th character is optional and can be of any kind
- if there are at least 2 characters the last one must not be a space

But in my result get all rows return, which are not NULL.

I then tried this regex `^([-0-9a-zA-Z])([-0-9a-zA-Z()\s]{0,18})([-0-9a-zA-Z\(\)]{0,1})$` (which I know is too strong because it only allows asci letters) but even with that I still get false results. I get the following three rows in my results

- Wrong results: `(Gebäude A)` and `Haus 1`
- Correct result: `auch` (Correct result because there is a trailing space)

So how can I fix my regex to only get the correct rows in which the col does not fullfills the requirements above. Note: German letters and things like paranthes must be accepted too.

Comment: `[.]` only matches a dot. You overused `[` and `]` brackets. Try [`'^\S(.{0,18}\S)?$'`](https://regex101.com/r/ZDTsIG/1)

Comment: So you don't want a row that doesn't not contain a line that starts with a non-whitespace? Please clarify you criteria

Comment: How does `-1` or `A` match your second rule of "has any letter, including regular space, in between the first and the last character"? Surely, you then need at least a 3-character string.

Comment: @MT0 This should emphasize, that in between the first and the last position there can be any letter, including space. The length requirement are 1 to 20 chars.

Comment: @bish The rule is not clear - I read it as the character in between is mandatory (so length 3-20) rather than optional (length 1-20). I've just edited the question to make it more clear that your intent is for this character to be optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when you put a shorthand character class into a bracket expression, it is parsed as a letter and a backslash patterns. `[\S]` matches `S` and `\` chars. `[.]` always matches a dot (i.e. it is the same as `\.`). Only use bracket expressions when you need to specify a specific character class (and then use POSIX character class inside them, e.g. `[:space:]` for whitespace).

You may use

```
^\S(.{0,18}\S)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDTsIG/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\S` - a non-whitespace
- `(.{0,18}\S)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `.{0,18}` - any 0 to 18 chars
  - `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Ah yeah *slamming head against the wall* - thank you for showing and explaining my mistake and providing a working solution!

Comment: @bish `[\S]` matches `S` **and** \ characters

Answer (score 3):

`[\S]` matches either the `\` character or the `S` character.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/207)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data( str, name ) AS (
  SELECT ' ', 'space' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '\', 'slash' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 's', 's' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'S', 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'n', 'n' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT CHR(13), 'CR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT CHR(10), 'LF' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   data
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( str, '[\S\n]' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/207/0)**:

```
| STR |  NAME |
|-----|-------|
|   \ | slash |
|   S |     S |
|   n |     n |
```

So in the above example, `[\S\n]` does not match a non-whitespace character or a carriage-return character but instead matches the `\`, `S` or `n` characters.

You just need:

```
SELECT *
from   table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (col, '^\S(.{0,18}\S)?$');
```

The regular expression `^\S(.{0,18}\S)?$` will match:

- `^` the start of the string
- `\S` a non-whitespace character
  (*rule - doesn't start with whitespace*)
- `(  )?` a capturing group that can be matched zero or one time containing:

  - `.{0,18}` between 0 and 18 other characters
    (*rule - may have any letter, including regular space, in between the first and the last character*)
    (*rule - has a length of at maximum 20 characters*)
  - `\S` a non-whitespace character
    (*rule - doesn't end with whitespace*)
- `$` the end of the string.